# how to create new user based on input values

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I have a problem and it's hard, too hard for me as a beginner. Can you please help me. I know this is kinda strange creating this with javascript but it's just my own project, nothing i will put on web. But i need this problem solved by using pure Vanilla Javascript, i have 
 users as shown below on .js and i have a page where i need to create i new user that can be logged in as same as other two(admin and guest), i need another guest user and created based on input values...Thanks in advance, i am still learning and comments would be appreciated as well..

```js
var el = document.getElementById("login");
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', state);
}

function state() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (username == "admin" && password == "admin") {
    sessionStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "yes");
    alert("You are logged in as ADMIN !");
    window.location.href = "../index.html";
  } else if (username == "guest" && password == "guest") {
    sessionStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "no");
    alert("You are logged in as GUEST !");
    window.location.href = "../index.html";
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username or password, try again !")
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1><span id="logo">mov</span>BLANK</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="newprojection" href="newprojection.html">New projection</a></li>
        <li><a id="buyticket" href="buyticket.html">Buy a ticket</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a id="newuser" href="newuser.html">New user</a></li>
        <li><a id="loginbtn" href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
        <li>
          <a id="nameofuser" href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <p>Function(admin/guest)</p>
    <input type="text" name="function" required>
    <a id="adduser" href="#">Add User</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first JavaScript line is `getElementById("login")`, but there is no element with the ID `login` in your HTML. And that's just the first line.

Answer (score 2):

you can save two data: value and key so add this function in your code.

```
function saveData() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if(!sessionStorage.getItem(username) == username) {
       sessionStorage.setItem(username, password);
  }else {
   alert(username + "already registered");

 }
}
```

update this

```
<input type="text" name="username" required id="username">
<p>Password</p>
<input type="password" name="password" required id="password">
<p>Repeat Password</p>
<input type="password" name="password" required>
<p>Function(admin/guest)</p>
<input type="text" name="function" required>
<a id="adduser" href="#" onclick="saveData();">Add User</a>
```

This is the logic, I hope I have helped

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array of valid users, rather than using if-else statements to check against each individual user (which can't be adapted to additional users).

```
const users = [
  { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' },
  { username: 'guest', password: 'guest' },
];
```

Then when you want to create a new user, push to that array. Verify logins with with:

```
function state() {
  const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  const foundUser = users.find(user => user.username === username && user.password === password);
  if (!foundUser) {
    console.log('Invalid user!');
  } else {
    // Log the user in
  }
}
```

Problem is, your current code *validates* a user login attempt (for which there isn't a button for), which can't (or *shouldn't*) be the same form as the form used to register, at least not without changing things around significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example, see below. The example is just for testing/learning purposes. I would recommend you to validate user and password using http requests and preventing sql injections.

PS: here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdLey6cp/24/

PS2: you can use sweet alert instead of alert: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

```
<input type="text" id="txt_user" placeholder="user">
<!--you should use type=password here, but set as text for test purposes-->
<input type="text" id="txt_password" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" id="createuser" value="create user">
<input type="submit" id="validateuser" value="validate new user">
<script>
    //adding event handlers
    document.querySelector('#createuser').onclick = create_user;
    document.querySelector('#validateuser').onclick = validate_user;

    function create_user()
    {
      //assign values for username and password
      var username = document.querySelector("#txt_user").value;
      var password = document.querySelector("#txt_password").value;
      //using sessionstorage to keep user and password values
      sessionStorage.setItem("username", username);
      sessionStorage.setItem("password", password);
      alert('new user is created');
    }

    function validate_user()
    {
      //getting previously recorded username and password
      var recorded_username = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
      var recorded_password = sessionStorage.getItem("password");
      //assign values for username and password
      var username = document.querySelector("#txt_user").value;
      var password = document.querySelector("#txt_password").value;
      //doing it as simple as possible, no filters (trim, lowercase) at all
      if (username==recorded_username && password==recorded_password)
      {alert('user and password are valid');}
      else
      {alert('validation error');}
    }
</script>
```